# Select images with a date in cordova-imagePicker

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using cordova-imagePicker to select multiple images from the camera roll. I need to allow the user to only be able to select images on a set date (for example images taken today).

I've been browsing the .java files but I really cannot find where to add some code to change the selection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the code in `onActivityResult()` for the `cursor.query()` method. there you can set the where clause in using this column of Media content provider `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED` to check the date range and get the specific set of images.

Comment: In the end, I've coded my own solution in JS. But thank you for your answer.